# 'MT_StaticRelease' not match 'MD_DynamicRelease' using cmake vcpkg

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries, boost-thread, vcpkg

I am stuck in a problem with Cmake on Windows 10.
I am using cmake with vcpkg to build an application linking to Boost thread (actually, I developed it on Ubuntu and I am now trying to build it also for Windows..)

The problem that I receive is:

> boost_thread-vc140-mt.lib (thread.obj): error LNK2038: mismatch
> detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': the value 'MT_StaticRelease' does not
> match the value 'MDd_DynamicDebug 'in mtconnect_get_data.obj

Here is my Cmake file:

```
# CMakeLists.txt


cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(mtconnect)


set(FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR "C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0")
include_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/include/jdbc)
include_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/include/jdbc/cppconn)
link_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/lib64/vs14)

set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR ${_VCPKG_INSTALLED_DIR}/x64-windows-static/include)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread)
include_directories(include ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}) 

find_package(CURL CONFIG REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS})


set(FULL_PATH_TO_LIBCONFIG_DIR my_libconfig_path)
include_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_LIBCONFIG_DIR}/include)
link_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_LIBCONFIG_DIR}/lib)
find_library(LIBCONFIGPP_LOCATION libconfig++)

set(FULL_PATH_TO_PTHREAD_DIR my_pthread_path )
include_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_PTHREAD_DIR}/include)
link_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_PTHREAD_DIR}/lib/x64)


include_directories(include)

set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS true)
set (Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF CACHE BOOL "use static libraries from Boost")
set (Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)


if (WIN32)
  add_definitions( -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB )
  add_definitions( -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK )
endif()

add_executable(mtconnect_create_data src/mtconnect_create_data.cpp)
add_executable(mtconnect_get_data src/mtconnect_get_data.cpp include/AsioTelnetClient.cpp)

target_link_libraries(mtconnect_create_data ${CURL_LIBRARY} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(mtconnect_get_data ${CURL_LIBRARY} ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    mysqlcppconn ${LIBCONFIGPP_LOCATION} pthread)
```

Answer (score 0):

...it seems to me to be solved by adding

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MT")
```

**just before** the add_executable line and building only the release